# How can I can split file contents in java by order of delimiters?

Tags: java, split

This is a part of the data am working on, the first split should be done after 6 spaces, the 2nd and 3rd split should be done after 4 spaces is there any way for that? Since am using this data for a dijkstra algorithm i just need to print the data as it is to make sure that they were read correctly.

```
      0    6371    1811
      1    6390    1811
      2    6416    1810
      3    6443    1810
      4    6390    1810
      5    6494    1810
      6    6553    1808
      7    6558    1808
      8    6638    1808
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way for that. Now read: [Why is “Is there a way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: [edit] your question and post your expected output.

Comment: `String[] segments = line.split("\\s+")` where segments at index `1`, `2` and `3` will be your numbers

Comment: Why do you care about the number of spaces in the first place? And note: when all your data has that fixed column layout, then you don't even need to use split. You can use substring() with fixed indexes instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone this was the solution: line.split("\\s+")